# A Data bound control from one table to write the values into another table

Tags: vb.net

I have a combobox in my userform on which I have applied the databinding. So when the form is loaded, it shows the values correctly from the table. In addition, I also have few text boxes in the same form into which the user is going to enter values. When the user is going to click on the submit button, I want the values in the text boxes and the combobox (which is showing values from a different table) to store into another table. So essentially my question is, can I use data binding for the combobox to show values from one table and write the same value into another table using data binding.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a foreign key relationship between these two tables, i.e. you are showing values from a parent table in the `ComboBox` and you want the corresponding ID to be saved into a foreign key column in a child table. In that case, you would query the parent table to get the ID and the value to display and bind that data to the `ComboBox`, e.g.

```sql
SELECT ParentId, ParentName FROM Parent
```

and then:

```vb
parentBindingSource.DataSource = parentDataTable

With parentComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "ParentName"
    .ValueMember = "ParentId"
    .DataSource = parentBindingSource
End With
```

The user will then see a list of `ParentName` values and, when they make a selection, you can get the corresponding `ParentId` from the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` and save it with your `TextBox` data.

You may also be able to bind the child data and have the user's selection pushed automatically, e.g. you have one or more child records in another `DataTable` bound to a `BindingSource`. If the foreign key column in the child table is named "ParentId", you could do this:

```vb
parentComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", childBindingSource, "ParentId")
```

If you are using a Data Source, that binding can also be configured in the designer.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. So I would presume that the data insertion into another table should use Insert query? and not like I can use the databinding option in the properties window? The reason I'm asking is, there are 20 different text boxes.

Comment: @ganeshsp, sorry that I didn't address your comment at the time. I imagine that this is too late to help you on this specific issue but it may help you or others anyway. You can get the `SelectedValue` yourself and set a field in the child record. Alternatively, you can bind the child data to one or more controls as well and have that `SelectedValue` pushed automatically. I have updated the answer to reflect that.